# Find parametrised method in unit test through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, automation, annotations

I have a Below sample code where I am trying to read the testid in after method , for method without parameters it works well , but My methods have Map as a parameter ..and it is failing.
I am not able to figure out how to read this testid in Aftermethod for parametrized method.-

Also In testng if say test1 failed then test2 will be skipped due to dependonMethod how can i still read this skipped method annotation value in aftermethod??

```
@Data(testId = 1623)
@Test(description = "test 1")
public void readTestAnnotation(Map<String,String> inputData) {
    logger.assertTrue(true, " test pass");
    logger.assertAll();
}


@Data(testId = 1645)
@Test(dependsOnMethods= {"readTestAnnotation"},  description = "test 
2")
public void readTestAnnotation1(Map<String,String> inputData) {
    logger.assertTrue(true," test failed");
    logger.assertAll();
}


@Data(testId = 1646)
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"readTestAnnotation1"}, description = 
"test3")
public void readTestAnnotation2(Map<String,String> inputData) {
    logger.assertTrue(true," test failed");
    logger.assertAll();
}


 @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void readtestId(ITestResult tr) throws NoSuchMethodException, 
SecurityException {
String methodName = tr.getMethod().getMethodName();
UseAsTestId ta = 
sampletest.class.getMethod(methodName).
   getAnnotation(UseAsTestRailId.class);

    System.out.println(ta.testRailId());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getMethod with Parameters types:

```
sampletest.class.getMethod(methodName).
   getAnnotation(UseAsTestRailId.class, Map.class);
```

Quotation from javadoc:

```
public Method getMethod(String name,
                         Class<?>... parameterTypes)
                  throws NoSuchMethodException,
                         SecurityException
```

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member
>   method of the class or interface
>
> > represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String
> >     specifying the simple name of the desired method. The parameterTypes
> >     parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's
> >     formal parameter types, in declared order. If parameterTypes is null,
> >     it is treated as if it were an empty array.

Comment: its not working , error- getAnnotation(Class<T>) in the type Method is not applicable for the arguments (Class<TestRailAnnotation.UseAsTestRailId>, Class<Map>).

Comment: error- getAnnotation(Class<T>)   ??? I thought we are talkimg about the getMethod method now. Did you get the getMethod to work ?

Comment: yeah sorry , i added in parameter type in get method ..but error is ->Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [readTestAnnotation] with [interface java.util.Map].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection